# How do I get square ends to arrows created with matplotlib's 'annotate'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have many places in my Python code where I use matplotlib's `annotate` to draw arrows with the general form

```
out_arrow = dict(arrowstyle='-', color=path_color, linewidth=4)    
ax.annotate('', xy=(x, y), xytext=(p, q), arrowprops=out_arrow)
```

but all of these arrows have rounded ends and I need them to be square (the arrows often abut, and I need them to appear continuous in that case).

How do I get square ends to arrows created with `annotate`?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with your rounded ends?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4332

Comment: @tom — Maybe I can just use lines for now.